# Getting Expression expected error in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a university website parser and there's a problem I can't cope with. For some reason I get an error on this line `Expression expected` and `Identifier expected`

```
articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class = "guide-box")
```

For full understanding, I am also attaching all the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_guide():
    headers = {
        'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    url = 'https://start.tpu.ru/guide/1'
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class = "guide-box")

    for article in articles_cards:
        article_title = article.find('h5').text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find('p5').text.strip()


        print(f'{article_title}|{article_desc}')

get_guide()
```

Comment: search by class: `soup.find_all("div",{"class":"guide-box"})`

Comment: Can't reproduce the error! and `articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class = "guide-box")` should be like `articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "guide-box")`, `class_` not `class`

Comment: + given website doesn't work without JavaScript. Output of `soup` is just `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `class` wrong in the `find_all`, you're using:

```py
soup.find_all("div", class = "guide-box")
```

However, the `class` should be part of the `attrs` obj:

```py
soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'guide-box'})
```

Or, if you use the latest bs4 version, the `class_` shortcut came into existence:

```py
soup.findAll('div', class_='guide-box')
```

---

For more info, refer to the `find_all()` [documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all).